# Add rules to a generateRandomNumber function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that generates a random number from a given interval, but I want to be able to generate only 3 identical consecutive numbers. For example, if a have the interval `[0,4)` I want:

- Accepted:   1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0
- Not accepted: 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0

I've found on multiple threads functions that generates a different number than the previous one, but I don't know how to change it to accomplish what I need. Any thoughts?

Comment: depending on what your usage case is, it is a bad idea to code too many rules into the function- the more you restrict randomness, the more patterns will arise.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't understand your rules with the given info and example. Please give a more elaborative example with some explanation

Comment: show us the code you wrote so far

Comment: You may store the last three numbers generated outside the function and check if the new generated number is not the same as the stored ones

Comment: Not so much clear on your question and language used.. However refer here for random number generation and use n-1, n-2 index within the new range to detect if there are any violations of the 3 consecutive rules. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must completely reset your counter, when you generate a different number. Not just decrease it.

```js
function setRandomInterval(min, max, allowedRepeats) {
  var last,            // keeping the last random value
      repeatCount = 0, // count of repeated value
      getR = function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; };

  if (min >= max) {
    throw 'Selected interval [' + min + ', ' + max + ') does not work for random numbers.';
  }
    
  return function () {
    var r = getR();
    if (r != last) {  
      repeatCount = 0;  //no repeat yet
    } else if (repeatCount < allowedRepeats) { //new number is equal to last one, but it's still ok
      repeatCount++;  //just increase the number of repeats
    } else {  //new number is equal to last, and allowed number of repeats is reached
      while (r == last) {  //must create a different number
        r = getR();
      }
      repeatCount = 0;  //reset the repeatCount
    }
    return last = r;  //save r as last number and return it
  };
}



var getRandom = setRandomInterval(0, 4, 2);  //call with 2 allowed repeats to allow a sequence of three equal numbers
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing me the details about the execution! I learned from it and I am grateful for the amount of time and effort you put into this helping me. The code works and I understand now where I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function randomBetween(min, max, limit = 3) {
  if (min > max) {
    [max, min] = [min, max];
  }

  function getBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  let last;
  let count = 0;

  return function generate() {
    const result = getBetween(min, max);

    count = (result === last) ? count + 1 : 0;

    if (count > limit) {
      return generate();
    }

    last = result;

    return result;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that prevent from the same number to randomize more than 3 times. If the `count` of the number is greater than the `limit` the `randomNumber` is called again (and so on until it won't get the same value.

You can see (when running it) that the largest sequence is 3.

```js
const limit = 3;
let last = null,
  count = 0;

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  let num = getRndInteger(min, max);
  if (last !== num) {
    last = num;
    count = 0;
  }
  count++;
  if (count > limit) {
    num = randomNumber(min, max);
  }
  return num;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  console.log(randomNumber(0, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that's uses a nice feature of modern JS.  Generators..

Using generators you can create composable code.  Instead of creating 1 function that does this one specific thing, you can compose a function than stream together multiple generators.  This is great for making re-usable code.

Below I've created 3 function,.

- **randomValues** => this just generates random number between a range.
- **repeatLimit** => this generator just prevents x amount of repeated values
- **iterCount** => this generator stop after count iterations

All you do then is compose all these generators together, but the bonus is that these generators can be used in other places.  eg.  `[...repeatLimit(3, [1,1,1,1, 0,0,0,0])]` would return `1,1,1,0,0,0`.

```js
function* randValues(min, max) {
  const range = max - min;
  while (true) 
    yield min + Math.trunc(Math.random() * range);
}

function* repeatLimit(limit, gen) {
  let rcount = 0, rvalue;
  for (let g of gen) {
    if (rvalue === g) rcount += 1; else rcount = 1;
    rvalue = g;
    if (rcount <= limit) yield g;
  }  
}

function* iterCount(count, gen) {
  for (let g of gen) {
    yield g;
    count --;
    if (count <= 0) break;
  }
}


const gen = 
  iterCount(22, repeatLimit(3, randValues(0, 2)));

for (const r of gen) {
  console.log(r);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for making this code so clean and re-usable. It works perfectly and I've learned from it more than I was thinking, I appreciate it!